# 12 Byte signed or unsigned integer

Tags: c++

How i can allocate 12 Byte signed or unsigned integer in c++. I have tried to build a structure that contains 3 unsigned integers but i didn't know how i would make the input number reside on these 3 correctly. So that when i overload the input operator i can distribute the bits over the 96bit i have in the 3 integers.
This is the structure i desire

```
struct type  
{ 
   unsigned int i;
   unsigned int j; 
   unsigned int k;
};
```

I tried to read it as string and then convert it to number and then to a string of 0's and 1's again, yet i have a problem with exactly inserting these in the proper bits.

Any suggestion !

Comment: What is your input (string) format? What is your output (string) format? Please give examples. Please copy-paste the code you have already written. Please declare the methods missing and show how they should behave.

Comment: For starters, you're assuming `unsigned int` is 32 bits; that's not guaranteed. Use `uint32_t`, defined in the `<cstdint>` header, if your implementation supports it.

Comment: what about XINT library? http://www.oakcircle.com/xint_docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction of the conversion can be implemented like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
struct type { uint32_t i, j, k; }; 
type binary_string_to_u96(const std::string &s) {
  type result = { 0, 0, 0 };
  const unsigned d = s.size() - 1;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    const uint32_t bit = s[d - i] == '1';
    if (i < 32) {
      result.k |= bit << i;
    } else if (i < 64) {
      result.j |= bit << (i - 32);
    } else {
      result.i |= bit << (i - 64);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

There are many alternative designs with their own benefits and complexity, this is only one of the possibilities.